# Sending RF signal after Serial input

Tags: arduino

I am trying to reproduce a simple 433mhz signal through an RF transmitter.  I have used RCSwitch to capture this signal and when I write a simple "Send" code, it works great - it turns off a light via a wireless outlet.  My issue is not really related to this hack.

If I use this code below, my signal comes out correctly.

```
  #include <RCSwitch.h>

RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

void setup() {
  mySwitch.enableTransmit(3);
   mySwitch.setPulseLength(183);
   mySwitch.setRepeatTransmit(6);
}

void loop() {
  mySwitch.send(5526835, 24);
  delay(5000);    
}
```

However, when I try to do something more complicated with this code using the serial input, my signal does not work.  As far as I can tell, the pulseLength gets set to 350 instead of my required 183.

My code is a little longs, so I will not post, but I am asking for an input from the Serial.  A "11" means device 1 ON and a "10" means device 1 OFF.   The code seems to work as expected and even gives an output signal, but the pulse length goes back to 350.  Is there something going on with an "interrupt" or is the Serial input doing something to my output signal?  I have even played around with interrupts but still cannot get this more complicated example to work.

EDIT: -  code to ask for what device

```
#include <RCSwitch.h>
RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

int inputData; int signalInt = 0;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   mySwitch.enableTransmit(3);
   mySwitch.setPulseLength(183);
   mySwitch.setProtocol(1);
   mySwitch.setRepeatTransmit(6);
}
void loop(){
  Serial.println("Enter Device ID Integer:");
  startProcess();
}

void startProcess(){
  while (Serial.available() > 0){
    inputData = Serial.parseInt();
    convertToDevice(inputData);
  } 
  startProcess();  
}

void convertToDevice(int input){
    String x = String(input);
    toggleDevice(x.charAt(0), x.charAt(1));
}

void toggleDevice(char deviceId, char sig){
   signalInt = 0;
   delay(2000); //only here to see if this helped
   if(deviceId == '1'){
       if(sig == '0'){ // device off  
          mySwitch.send(5526844, 24); 
          delay(2000);
          startProcess();
        }
        if(sig == '1'){ // device on
           mySwitch.send(5526835, 24);
           delay(2000);

          startProcess();
        }
    } // end device 1
    if(signalInt == 0){
      Serial.println('Nope, wrong code');
      startProcess();
    }

}
```

Comment: can't you at least post some parts of your code? making your code readable will also improve our/your understanding of what might go wrong :)

Comment: Sorry about that.  Cleaned up the code.  The expected input would be "11" to turn on.  If I attach the receiver to this same breadboard/arduino, I get a transmission, but at 350 pulse length.

Comment: You are certainly using calls to startProcess() a lot :) After the first call to startProcess in void loop() startProcess() calls itself recursively, you would run out of memory fast... _In a recursive function there must always be an exit condition!_ In addition there are more calls to startProcess() littered through the code. Maybe you should check the serial buffer content in the loop, then call startProcess if there is data. Remove the recursive call in startProcess(), and rethink the rest of the logic flow.

Comment: I've stripped this to the bones and still get the same issue.  I cannot get the pulse length below 350 if I use Serial.print() at any point in the code.  Not sure if this is related, but the same issue happens on my Raspberry Pi using the same logic (RCSwitch library as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NB Pulse length must be set AFTER Protocol because setProtocol(1) also sets pulse length = 350.
```

You should try:

```
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   mySwitch.enableTransmit(3);
   mySwitch.setProtocol(1);
   mySwitch.setPulseLength(183);
   mySwitch.setRepeatTransmit(6);
}
```

Comment: That did it!  Must have missed that when I was looking though the code.  Thanks.